# Buidling an Extension to Trigger an onClick Action in the website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclick

I'm new to google chrome extensions, but I'm quite familiar with HTML and some javascript. My main area of expertise is Objective-C (but that's a different area).

I wanted to build a chrome extension where I want to replace a website's button with a different custom button (The button uses a specific class/ID). For example if a website were to have a button that said "Tweet Us" I would want to change it to "Email Us", change the onClick action and the button image.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any tutorials or samples that touch on this. Most that I've ran into focus more on building UIs by the bookmark browser, but I don't really have use for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with reading [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Add to the manifest.json the URL you want to manipulate under "matches".

Also add to the manifest.json your JavaScript + css (under "content_scripts").

In the JavaScript write some code that deletes the current button and replace it with your button and

your event for that button.

The easiest way to write it is with Jquery.